# Kendo ui export csv

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

Currently the export to csv work fine and currently export all. Is there anyway i can put filter to export only based on the row selected?. Please advise. OnChange event it will pass in the ID to the controller. But I just need to find out if button Export click, it also hit the OnChange event

View:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<HAp.Models.SessionModel>()

        .Name("List")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @Style = "align:center; font-size:10.5px; length:100%" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {

            columns.Bound(p => p.ReftID).Visible(false);
            columns.Bound(p => p.CreateDate);
            columns.Bound(p => p.CreateBy)
            columns.Bound(p => p.Description);



        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .ToolBar(toolBar =>
                    toolBar.Custom()
                        .Text("Export To CSV")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
                        .Url(Url.Action("Export", "Index", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~" }))
                )
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Selectable(s => s.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridSelectionMode.Single))
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()//bind with Ajax instead server bind
            .PageSize(10)
            .ServerOperation(true)
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ReftID))
                                .
            .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDataBound").Change("onChange"))

    )


    function onChange(e) {
           var grid = $('#List').data('kendoGrid');   //get a reference to the grid data 
           var record = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); //get a reference to the currently selected row
           var GuidID = record.ReftID;

           $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "@(Url.Content("~/Test/Export/"))",
                    data: {
                            "ID": GuidID
                    }               
                });


        }

function onDataBound(e) {
        var grid = $('#List').data('kendoGrid');


            // ask the parameterMap to create the request object for you
            var requestObject = (new kendo.data.transports["aspnetmvc-server"]({ prefix: "" }))
            .options.parameterMap({
                page: grid.dataSource.page(),
                sort: grid.dataSource.sort(),
                filter: grid.dataSource.filter()
            });

            // Get the export link as jQuery object
            var $exportLink = $('#export');

            // Get its 'href' attribute - the URL where it would navigate to
            var href = $exportLink.attr('href');

            // Update the 'page' parameter with the grid's current page
            href = href.replace(/page=([^&]*)/, 'page=' + requestObject.page || '~');

            // Update the 'sort' parameter with the grid's current sort descriptor
            href = href.replace(/sort=([^&]*)/, 'sort=' + requestObject.sort || '~');

            // Update the 'pageSize' parameter with the grid's current pageSize
            href = href.replace(/pageSize=([^&]*)/, 'pageSize=' + grid.dataSource._pageSize);

            //update filter descriptor with the filters applied

            href = href.replace(/filter=([^&]*)/, 'filter=' + (requestObject.filter || '~'));

            // Update the 'href' attribute
            $exportLink.attr('href', href);
        }

    Controller:

    public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
            {

                IEnumerable list = db.GetAll();
                MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8);

                writer.Write("Ref ID,");
                writer.Write("Create Date,");
                writer.Write("Create By,");
                writer.Write("List Description,");
                writer.Write("List Status,");


                writer.WriteLine();
                foreach (vwListDetail lists in list)
                {
                    writer.Write(lists .RefID);
                    writer.Write(",");
                    writer.Write(lists .CreateDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
                    writer.Write(",");
                    writer.Write(lists .CreatedBy);
                    writer.Write(",");
                    writer.Write(lists .ListDescription);
                    writer.Write(",");



                    writer.WriteLine();
                }
                writer.Flush();
                output.Position = 0;

                return File(output, "text/comma-separated-values", "List.csv");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
IEnumerable list = db.GetAll.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
```

This code should do any paging, sorting or filtering.

Comment: Thank you. But still not filtering. Do we need to pass in in View (cshtml page)

Comment: I don't understand you. Please clarify.

Comment: IEnumerable list = db.GetAll.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data; it would not filter the record based on the selected row. It will return all when exporting. SHould we need pass the selected row id in cshtml file?

Comment: If you need just one row you need somehow to identify it. So yes you should pass the row id to the controller. You don't need ToDataSourceResult then.

Comment: Hi Atanas, I am unsure where i should put the filter on selected row. Any ideas?.

Comment: Well use the grid API to get the selected row. http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#select will return them and http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#dataitem will get the associated data item.

Comment: Hi Atanas, I able to pass the ID to the controller by using onChange event. However, I need to pass the ID when the Export button is click. Please let me know how i can achieve this?

Comment: Use the grid API to get the selected ID and add it to the "href" of the link.

Comment: HI Atanas, Sorry for the question again. For instance: I got the selected record id by using the following: var grid = $('#List').data('kendoGrid');    
           var record = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); 
           var GuidID = record.ReftID; The thing is i could not place this code under OnShowDetails(e), could you please let me know  where i should specified. then how exactly in adding in href worked. Please advise. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Or is that possible if i could add onChange function in href since it has already pickup the row id. if yes how i can achieve this?

Comment: I have no clue what OnShowDetails is. And I already told you what to do "Use the grid API to get the selected ID and add it to the "href" of the link". Something like  $exportLink.attr('href', href + "&GuidID=" + GuidID);

Comment: Do not forget to mark my response as an answer if it helped.